# Orbits of the group action $g. (x,y) = (gx,gy)$ on cartesian product

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Let $G$ be a group acting on a set $X$. Then we have a natural action on $X \times X$ in the following way: $g. (x,y) = (gx,gy)$. Then, suppose we have two points of interest $x_1,x_2 \in X$, and we know their orbits under $G$. Is there some procedure to help up calculate the orbit of $(x_1,x_2)$?

edit: for what it's worth, both $G$ and $X$ are finite.

Comment: What do you mean by calculating the orbit? The orbit is the orbit. Do you mean the size of the orbit? The isomorphism classes of orbits (as $G$-sets) are in bijection with the coset spaces $G/H$ accompanying conjugacy classes of subgroups $H$, so you could ask for the class of $H$ corresponding to $(x,y)\in X\times Y$.

Comment: @blue Probably OP means, if you know the orbits of $x_1$ and $x_2$ (under $G$ in $X$), how do you construct the orbit of $(x_1, x_2)$ (under $G$ in $X \times X$), from those two?

Comment: @M.Vinay Typo fixed, thanks. Yes, constructing the orbit in that way is exactly what I mean.

Comment: @nigelvr If you can represent $G$ with some (arbitrary) ordering, and $(g(x_1))_{g \in G} = (y_{1(g)})_{g \in G}$ (say) is the orbit of $x_1$ in $G$, written in this order, and $((g(x_2))_{g \in G} = (y_{2(g)})_{g \in G}$ is defined similarly, then the orbit of $(x_1, x_2)$ is $(y_{1(g)}, y_{2(g)})_{g \in G}$ [obtained by *zipping* the "lists" $(x_{1(g)})$ and $(x_{2(g)})$].

Comment: @nigelvr Are $G$ and $X$ infinite? The notation would be much simpler if one or both were finite, or at least countable.

Comment: I don't see why there should be some purely set-theoretic operation on the orbits of $x_1$ and $x_2$ that would give is the orbit of $(x_1,x_2)$. What do we mean by "constructing __ from __," in precise terms? What's allowed, what isn't? If I write down an irredundant listing of the elements of the orbit of $(x,y)\in X\times Y$ using the stabilizers of $x$ and $y$, would that work? What if I provide the isomorphism type of the orbit, as a $G$-set?

Comment: @M.Vinay The only difference I can tell between your comment and saying "the orbit of $(x,y)\in X\times Y$ is $\{(gx,gy):g\in G\}$" (which is basically equivalent to "the orbit is the orbit," as I stated) is that you've made $G$ ordered. (Your orbit listing has many repetitions in general, too; are we okay with that?) Often when we want to make things very explicit and constructive, we have to put orders on sets, but is that really all there is to this question?

Comment: @blue I was thinking pretty much the same when writing that. That what I've written is almost equivalent to the definition of the orbit. But as I have understood the question, it is indeed asking for this (very simple) method of "writing down" the orbit of the pair, if the orbits of the elements of the pair were given in the form of sets. Only unless the sets are ordered, I don't see how anything can be done.

Comment: Let $T$ and $S$ be transversals for $G/S_x$ and $S_x/(S_x\cap S_y)$ respectively. Then the orbit of $(x,y)\in X\times Y$ is $\{(tx,tsy):t\in T,s\in S\}$, and furthermore this is an irredundant parametrization, in the sense that if two tuples are equal, $(tx,tsy)=(\bar{t}x,\bar{t}\bar{s}y)$ for $t,\bar{t}\in T$, $s,\bar{s}\in S$ then $t=\bar{t},s=\bar{s}$. Is this of interest? I can also tell you that the orbit of $(x,y)$ is isomorphic to $G/(S_x\cap S_y)$, although this is more trivial. I can also give the more general orbital decomposition $G/H\times G/K\cong\bigsqcup_{HgK}G/(H\cap K^g)$.